# CMAKE inherit definition from parent

Tags: cmake

I am writing some definition in parent CMakeLists.txt 
I want those definition got inherited in sub directory of the project. 
So If I have project like

```
root
  |- CMakeLists.txt
  |- A 
  |  |- CMakeLists.txt
  |- B 
     |- CMakeLists.txt
```

the definition I had written in root CMakeLists.txt should go to child.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the order of include made those changes. In past I was using

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.0)
SET(ENV{OSDEP} "linux")
SET(ENV{BIT} 64)
SET(ENV{XUL} 5000)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(lib/src/json)
add_definitions("-_DDEBUG")
```

which I changed last two line to

```
add_definitions("-_DDEBUG")
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(lib/src/json)
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how you use A's and B's CMakeLists.txt in CMakeLists.txt.

The CMAKE-way is to do add_subdirectory (and I strongly recommend it, after having struggled quite a while) in root's CMakeLists.txt for A and B. Then A and B have all variables from root and root has all targets available from A and B.